# Only 1 array of objects is outputted

Tags: jquery, arrays, local-storage

In localStorage I have several arrays of objects, I tried to do this:

```
var recipes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
$(recipes).each(function(index, recipe){
    $('#qq').html(recipe.title);
    console.log(recipe);
});
```

However, it only outputs last array of objects, and console.log(recipe) contains more:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, please?

Sample:

```
[{"title":"q","ingredients":"s","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110052397224993886441":{"display":""}}},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311079670549304635711":{"display":""}}},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311016424488798697091":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"q","instructions":"a","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311067483883379310751":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110317360085863979571":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"qfsdf","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110046219695216345611":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"d","instructions":"f","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311092867615674104551":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311033441653883910961":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"f","ingredients":"d","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311072398853052545851":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"ffsf","ingredients":"d","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311023649491136232761":{"display":""}},"salutation":"french"}]
```

Comment: Definitely use a `for` loop instead of `.each`.

Comment: Why are you "wrapping" the recipes in a jQuery object? O.o `$(recipes).each(function() { ... })` -> `$.each(recipes, function() { ... })`

Comment: @Andreas can you post an answer on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `$('#qq').html(recipe.title);` overwrites the content of `#qq` on each iteration, hence only the last entry of `recipes` will be visible.

Use [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

```js
var recipes = [{"title":"q","ingredients":"s","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110052397224993886441":{"display":""}}},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311079670549304635711":{"display":""}}},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311016424488798697091":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"q","instructions":"a","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311067483883379310751":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110317360085863979571":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"qfsdf","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110046219695216345611":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"d","instructions":"f","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311092867615674104551":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311033441653883910961":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"f","ingredients":"d","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311072398853052545851":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"ffsf","ingredients":"d","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311023649491136232761":{"display":""}},"salutation":"french"}];

$.each(recipes, function(index, recipe){
    $('#qq').append("<li>" + recipe.title + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="qq"></ul>
```

Or add the title to the current content of `#qq` with [`.html(function(index, oldValue) { ... })`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
var recipes = [{"title":"q","ingredients":"s","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110052397224993886441":{"display":""}}},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311079670549304635711":{"display":""}}},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311016424488798697091":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"q","instructions":"a","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311067483883379310751":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110317360085863979571":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"qfsdf","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery3110046219695216345611":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"d","instructions":"f","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311092867615674104551":{"display":""}},"salutation":"polish"},{"title":"q","ingredients":"w","instructions":"e","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311033441653883910961":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"f","ingredients":"d","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311072398853052545851":{"display":""}},"salutation":"italian"},{"title":"ffsf","ingredients":"d","instructions":"d","moreingredients":[],"moreinstruction":[],"img":{"jQuery311023649491136232761":{"display":""}},"salutation":"french"}];

$.each(recipes, function(index, recipe){
    $('#qq').html(function(_, oldValue) { return oldValue + recipe.title + "<br />" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qq"></div>
```

There are many more options to manipulate the DOM:
[jQuery Learning Center: Manipulating Elements](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/)

Comment: Works great! thanks! what if I would like to delete a specific entry if button is pressed?

Comment: It depends... Head over to [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/) or give the search on SO a try. You will have to find a way to get the element you wan't to remove. The removal is the easy part: [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: I was thinking on something like: for each array create a div with it=qq and increase it by 1 for each array. And then loop throught them and if one of them is clicked, do .remove. is that possible?

Comment: It depends... :) Give it a try and if you have any problems you can ask another question (but please not in a comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321823/402037)